# Handle Event With React Functional Component - Receiving Not Defined Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

With a class component, I could handle an event similar to the code below w/o any problems, but with a functional component, I get a `'handleHover' is not defined  no-undef` error.

How can I handle events when usijng React's functional component?

```
const NavBar = () => {

  handleHover = () => {
    // run code
  }

  return(
    <ul className="nav">
        <li>
          <a onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}>Products</a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
  )

}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: To get rid of the lint error, `handleHover = () => {` should be `const handleHover = () => {`. Also, refer to it with `onMouseEnter={handleHover}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it’s not a class you should remove this before function name.
Also add const before the function declaration.

```
const handleHover = () => {}
onMouseEnter={handleHover}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways (at least that I know xD):

```
function handleHover() {}
```

or

```
const handleHover = () => {}
```